# Writing out frames in OpenCV with threshold

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, motion-detection

I'm attempting to write out frames to video from OpenCV using thresholding criteria to specify which frames to write out.

I produce a motion index by comparing inter-frame pixel intensities and aim to autoremove segments of video in which the motion index is less than a defined threshold (when the person in the video isn't moving).

Unfortunately when I plot my motion index I see the following:
[image: Motion Index trace, with user-defined segment overlayed(orange) and subsequent threshold plotted as horizontal line.]
(Figure 1: Motion Index trace plotted against frame number, with user-defined segment overlaid (orange) and subsequent threshold plotted as horizontal line. - the threshold is defined as the mean of the user defined region, plus 3 times Standard Deviation.)

As evidenced by my plot, the periods of high motion index values frequently drop below my threshold before quickly rising again. With my code currently as it is, it will not write those subthreshold frames to file, when I want them to be included. What I want to be able to do is define regions of the graph where the motion index is **sustained above or below the threshold for an arbitrary number of frames in a row** - i.e. I want to only write out video frames where the motion occurs above the threshold for a sustained period of time, and not write the areas where the motion index trace is below threshold.

Currently my code only compares one frame to the next in a loop to produce the list of motion index values, so comparing multiple frames together to see if there is a sustained set of above-threshold values isn't possible. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

I appreciate this may be a bit confusing to follow - if any clarification is required please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

```
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import numpy as np 
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 


MIList =[]

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

selectedvideo = askopenfilename()
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(selectedvideo)
length = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
intlength = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))
currentframenumber = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES)
intcurrentframenumber = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))
scaling_factor = 1
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter((selectedvideo + 'motionindexed.avi'),fourcc, 60.0, (640,478), isColor=False)
with open((selectedvideo + 'threshold' + '.txt'), 'r') as readthreshold:
    threshold = float(readthreshold.readline())

def frame_diff(prev_frame, cur_frame, next_frame):
    diff_frames1 = cv2.absdiff(next_frame, cur_frame)

    diff_frames2 = cv2.absdiff(cur_frame, prev_frame)

    return cv2.bitwise_and(diff_frames1, diff_frames2)

def get_frame(cap):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == True:
        scaling_factor = 1
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, None, fx = scaling_factor, fy = scaling_factor, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        return cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    prev_frame = get_frame(cap)
    cur_frame = get_frame(cap)
    next_frame = get_frame(cap)

    while (cap.isOpened()):

        try:
            cv2.imshow("Object Movement", frame_diff(prev_frame, cur_frame, next_frame))
            prev_frame = cur_frame
            cur_frame = next_frame
            next_frame = get_frame(cap)
            differencesquared = (next_frame-cur_frame)**2
            interframedifference = np.sum(differencesquared)
            MIList.append(interframedifference)
            print(interframedifference)
            if interframedifference > threshold:
                out.write(cur_frame)

            key = cv2.waitKey(1)
            if key == ord('q'):
                break
        except:
            break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```